# Minimal set of files for Spring Boot Git info to work

Tags: spring, git, spring-boot, docker

What are the minimal set of files in the `.git` folder so that

```
id("com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties") version "2.4.1"
```

would work?

That way I can ignore them in `.dockerignore`

So far I have this

```
.git/FETCH_HEAD
.git/AUTO_MERGE
.git/fs-monitor--daemon/
.git/ORIG_HEAD
.git/hooks/
.git/logs/
.git/refs/
```